# Node+Express+NGINX application returning localhost instead of domain

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have a node+express website running on my ubuntu server on port 10000 with nginx on port 80 using a proxy_pass to localhost:10000.  My issue is that when I ask for the host in express it returns localhost instead of my domain name.  I use the nginx proxy so I can manage several domains on the machine pointing to different applications.

Is there a way to keep the original host name on my node+express server while still using proxy_pass in nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `nginx` sets the Host header in the upstream request to the hostname appearing in the `proxy_pass` statement. In this case `localhost`.

You need to set the Host header explicitly using the `proxy_set_header` directive.

For example, I always set this group:

```
proxy_set_header  Host               $host;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding    "";
proxy_set_header  Proxy              "";
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for more.