# How to run a express server using nginx in localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to run the express server using Nginx in localhost.
Is it possible? If it is possible how can I achieve that?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

Comment: You want nginx to run express embeded? that's not posible for what i understand, you need to run the express app on some port and then reverse proxy that port with nginx (express and nginx work independently), check the docs: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/.

Comment: What does "I want to run the express server using Nginx in localhost" mean?  Nginx is an independent program and not a node.js program.  Express runs only in node.js.  Usually, when you combine nginx with Express, you direct the incoming requests to nginx.  It then applies whatever you want nginx to do and then forwards remaining requests to your express port (which, if on the same host, is a different port from what the user connected to).

Comment: In this way, you can use nginx for a whole bunch of things such as serving static content, providing various security features, etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node+Express+NGINX application returning localhost instead of domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478436/nodeexpressnginx-application-returning-localhost-instead-of-domain)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use nginx as a reverse proxy for express you can configure your server as follow:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #port where you are serving your express app.

  }
}
```

You should make your configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

After change the configuration file, check if there is no error in your script:

```
$sudo nginx -t
```

Expected result should be:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

After configuration is ok, you should restart your nginx instance, with command:

```
$sudo nginx -s reload
```

After proper reload assert your node/express server is running. Now if you access `http://localhost` you should see what's is listening in `http://localhost:3000`

Nginx should be serving your instance, when you stop your nodes / express you should see default error 502.

If any questions check [this document](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#example) as a resource.

Comment: what ip address should I use in server_name?
I have used 127.0.0.1,
but when I run port 80 from browser it only shows the default app, not the app running on  localhost:3000

Comment: Or I need to give all those command from a ssh server?

Comment: you should access via browser, using your real ip, to check your real ip just use command `ifconfig` Should use port 3000 too when accessing with your real ip.

Comment: well, I get my ip using `curl ifconfig.me` and I gave that value as server_name.

But, then I tried to visit myip:3000 from browser

and it doesnt run the app.

Comment: Just updated answer. After alter your nginx default file, remember do the `$sudo nginx -s reload`